# Правильная обработка ошибки БД

Tags: python, django

подскажите пожалуйста как правильно обрабатывать ошибку записи в базу данных

у меня в контроллере есть такой кусок кода:

```
if form.is_valid(): 
    try:
        obj.family = form.cleaned_data.get('login')
        obj.save()  
    except DatabaseError:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/DBerror/')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/ok_page/')
```

он в случае успешной записи переправляет пользователя на определённую страницу, а в случае возникновения ошибки при записи - отправляет пользователя на другую страницу(которая выводит сообщение об ошибке)

не существует ли стандартного способа информировать пользователя о произошедшей ошибке и при этом не создавать ручками страницу DBerror

Comment: ну в Django принято сохранить форму, и если .is_valid() вернет True, то после form.save() данные формы должны сохраниться в базу и подобных ошибок ожидать не надо, а если форма не валидная, то ошибочки культурно описаны в form.errors

Comment: а если форма валидная, но отвалилось соединение с БД? и соответственно данные не записаллись

Comment: ну не знаю, как-то за два с половиной года такого не случалось

Comment: Если отвалилась база то пользователь увидит 500 ошибку.

А знать что именно у вас отвалилось ему ни к чему.